# Android: Deep Links / Crawl errors / Content mismatch / Blocks resources on the app page

Tags: android, facebook, web-crawler, facebook-android-sdk, deep-linking

We recently add Google Deep Linking to our Web and our Android App.
In our Web page and in the Android App, we work with Collections of Post (quotes).

[This is the Android App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.frenys.appexpress)

We are having a lot of Crawl errors in the WebMaster page. The kind of "Content mismatch" error.

This is an example of Web Content and Android App content of one error:

[This is the link of the Web page (a post inside the 'Postales Navideñas' Collection)](http://frenys.com/post/6063811-/)

And this is the link for the deep linking to our Android App (to the same 'Post')

android-app://com.frenys.appexpress/frenys/?c=1012828&p=6063811

We believe that the content is the same, when the 'deep link' starts the Android App, the same 'Post' that shows in the Web Page is showed in the Android App.
No other content is showed first (no dialogs, no other screen, no splash screen)

The WebMaster Site shows that the detail of the error is  that we are bloking resources on the App page, and the the one url that shows as blocked by the Android App is:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/xxxxxxxxxxx?format=json&sdk=android&fields=supports_attribution%2Csupports_implicit_sdk_logging%2Cgdpv4_nux_content%2Cgdpv4_nux_enabled%2Candroid_dialog_configs
```

(the "xxxxxxxxxxx" in the Url is our Facebook App Id)

That is an Url used by the Facebook SDK for Android (we have a Share via Facebook in the Android Screen of the 'Post'),

We don't block this resource, is an internal resource of an SDK outside our App. 
How can we remove this error?

Thanks,

Valeria

**Edit:** (12/12/2014)

Hi,

We'll still have these errors of 'Content Mismatch', but there are some things we discovered and they can be helpful.

One:

We carried many tests, and we realized that in our URI link for the 'deep link' to the Android App we use 2 parameters (android-app://com.frenys.appexpress/frenys/?c=1012828&p=6063811), and there seems to be a bug in the adb (using the "adb shell am start -a" command). We initially test this link with the 'Qr Code tool', and with that tool we enter to the same content. Thus, both parameters were taken into account. BUT, with the 'adb' tool, we found out  that the adb only took ONE parameter of the URI. Content thereof was different.

Our errors of 'mismatch content' were less after changing our Uri.

Two:

With other errors (Example: "Your apps back button does not send users back to search results") we discovered that Android documentation about deep linking sometimes not reflect the functionality that the WebMaster expects. That caused us to have other errors detected by Webmaster.

Maybe this information can be helpful. For us with this 'deep linking' errors is to try and see in the next days if it works.